# Undoing Encoding Translations

Tags: ruby

I wrote a simple ftp client that was downloading some zip files from a client site.  For all intents and purposes the code looked like this:

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new
ftp.connect 'ftp.server.com'
ftp.login 'user', 'pwd'
ftp.binary = true
t = Tempfile.new 'file'
ftp.getbinaryfile('remotefile', nil) {|data| t << data}
t.close
ftp.close
FileUtils.mv t, '/path/to/file'
```

This ran fine and dandy when it was running on a Linux box, but when the code got moved to a Windows box the binary data started getting corrupted and I had to set the tempfile into binmode before writing to it.

My question: Is there any way I can "fix" or undo the encoding translations that were done when the zip files were originally downloaded and corrupted to get those files back, essentially going from the encoding back to binary?

Some further info from the Windows box the code was running from

```
t = Tempfile.new('file')
t.external_encoding # -> nil
t.internal_encoding # -> nil
Encoding.default_internal # -> nil
Encoding.default_external.name # -> "IBM437"
```

Comment: i think that you can re-read the files in non binary mode on the windows box and write it out again with binary mode on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the data get corrupted while saving into the file, not while downloading.

On Windows, text file lines are separated with CR+LF. If you open a file in text mode and write CR byte into it, the CR automatically gets replaced with CR+LF.

Zip files are binary files. Use binary mode to work with them.

Comment: Sergey, you were absolutely right, it was the EOL conversion that was causing the issue, not the encoding.  I just ran a couple of the corrupted zips through dos2unix and was able to extract the data in them.  Thanks!